# TFS 2012 deployer mapping parameter not passed to powershell

Tags: powershell-3.0

From what I've read, this should work so I don't see the issue.

I have a DeploymentMapping as such:

```
  <Mapping
   BuildDefinitionPattern="^MyProject$"
       Computer="myserver"
       OriginalQuality="*"
       NewQuality="Released"
       Script="myscript.ps1"
       RunnerType="PowerShell"
       NotificationAddress="me@myemail.com">
       <ScriptParameter name="Myparam" value="one" />
  </Mapping>
```

And the ps1:

```
param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$Myparam
)

Write-Host script done
```

**Cannot process command because of one or more miss
ERROR: ing mandatory parameters:Myparam**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. TFS doesn't pass the script parameter as a param to powershell, but as a variable.

Instead of

```
param (
  $MyParam
)
```

You would just reference $MyParam in the script.